# PHP form stopped sending emails from submissions

Tags: php, forms, function, email, undefined

I am getting issues on the 4th line. Everyone time someone submits and email is a vaild entry I get this error

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function eregi() in /homepages/29/d409157025/htdocs/contacts.php:31 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /homepages/29/d409157025/htdocs/contacts.php on line 4

The form was working perfectly since I uploaded it, thats been over a year.

```
//Check to make sure sure that a valid email address is submitted
if(trim($_POST['email']) == '')  {
    $hasError = true;
} else if (!eregi("^[A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9._%-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$", trim($_POST['email']))) {
    $hasError = true;
} else {
    $email = trim($_POST['email']);
}

//Check to make sure comments were entered
if(trim($_POST['message']) == '') {
    $hasError = true;
} else {
    if(function_exists('stripslashes')) {
        $comments = stripslashes(trim($_POST['message']));
    } else {
        $comments = trim($_POST['message']);
    }
}

//If there is no error, send the email
if(!isset($hasError)) {
    $emailTo = 'info@roswellhistoriccottage.com, artem.alek@icloud.com'; //Put your own email address here
    $body = "Name: $name \n\nEmail: $email \n\nComments:\n $comments";
    $headers = 'From: RHC Website Information Request <'.$emailTo.'>' . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: ' . $email;

    mail($emailTo, $subject, $body, $headers);
    $emailSent = true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [eregi()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eregi.php) function is deprecated and was removed in PHP 7. It appears you or your host recently updated you to PHP 7.

To fix the issue, you need to change the code to use [preg_match()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) instead.

Comment: thanks! I really appreciate it. I figured something like this was the issues, just wasn't clear in a lot of research I did. Blessings!